# How to print a list of release versions next to the product in C# .net mvc 5?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Suppose I have a database like this

```
Product  Version
a          1.2
a          1.3
a          1.4
a          1.5
b          1.1
b          1.2
c          1.0
```

I want to print this in the view as

```
**a** 1.2, 1.3, 1.4 1.5 
**b** 1.1, 1.2 
**c** 1.0
```

I am able to get the product and version next to each other but in the data base format. How to I print the output as desired. Please help

Answer (score 0):

```
   List<ProductVersion> Products=
        listOfProducts.GroupBy(x=>x.Product)
        .Select(y=>new ProductVersion{
            productId = y.Key
        ,   version = y.SelectMany(x=>x. version).ToList()
        });
```

Comment: Are you sure EF is able to translate this to SQL ? Maybe OP must load all rows in memory before to aggregate them. Besides, this will generate a sublist of "version", not a single string as requested by OP.

Comment: you can make single string by String.Join(", ", names.ToArray());

Comment: Yes. Or with Aggregate function. But the point is still the same : this is ok with linq to objects but it's not directly usable against a DB. The OP is not clear about this requirement and we are not even sure he uses Entity Framework, but the first post clearly states about a DB. But if the data set is little, he will do this in Linq to Objects, and your query will indeed be useful for him.